toolbar_sticky option in RichText TinyMCE Oracle APEX
how could I have toolbar_sticky : true option in richtext TinyMCE for oracle APEX ??
I've tried this in Initialization JavaScript Function section but it didn't apply on richtext.
function(options) {
 options.editorOptions.toolbar_sticky =  true;
   return options;
}

Also APEX version is 23.1.

After trying many syntaxes and reading https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/latest/toolbar-configuration-options/ document , finally I've found the solution :
function(options) {
options.editorOptions.toolbar_sticky = true;
options.editorOptions.toolbar_sticky_offset = 100; /*based on fixed header height in px */
return options;
}

the only I had forgot is toolbar_sticky_offset option ! when I have a fixed position header in page , this option should have a pixel amount to stick below the header's page .
